# How do I assign Y to X?

Tags: swift, xcode

I couldn't figure out how to copy value of variable into another variable in Swift, an example code for this in python would be

```
def assignVariable():
    x=1
    y=x
    return y
RESULT 1
```

When I did this it doesn't seem to work in Swift. Is there any solution to this or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: problem is at

```
var originalCount=countDown
```

it gave me `Use of unresolved identifier 'countDown'` but when I assign it literally it works. Here's my swift code

```
import Cocoa

class MainWindow: NSWindowController {
    var hitCount = 0
    var started:Bool = false
    var timer = 10
    var colorList: [NSColor] = [ NSColor.black,NSColor.blue,NSColor.brown,NSColor.cyan,NSColor.darkGray,NSColor.gray,NSColor.green,NSColor.lightGray,NSColor.magenta,NSColor.orange,NSColor.purple,NSColor.red,NSColor.white,NSColor.yellow]
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrubber1: NSScrubber!
    @IBOutlet weak var display: NSTextField!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }
    var countdown=10
    var originalCount=countDown
    //(countdown,originalCount) = (10,10) //it works if i use this instead
    func startGame(){
        if(countDown>0 || started==true){
            display.stringValue=String(countDown)
            countDown-=1
            let seconds = 1.0
                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
                    self.startGame()
                 }
        }else{
            display.stringValue="Done "+String(hitCount)+" Taps in " + String(originalCount) + "Tap to RESET"
            started=false
            countDown=10;
        }
    }
    @IBAction func labelPress(_ sender: Any) {
        display.stringValue="__RESET__"
        hitCount=0
        countDown=10
        started=false
    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if started==false{
            startGame()
        }
        button1.bezelColor = colorList[Int.random(in: 0..<colorList.count)]
        started=true
        button1.title=String(hitCount)
        hitCount+=1
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't Python *or* Swift.  Post the code you are actually trying to run and describe the problem you see when it fails.  If there's an error message, copy and paste it int your question.

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, I have updated the question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialise one variable with another at the top level in your class. Looking at your code I don't think that originalCount needs to be a property, move it inside `startGame()` instead and make it a local variable and also use `let` since it isn't changing

```
var countdown=10

func startGame(){
    let originalCount = countDown
    if(countDown>0 || started==true){
        ...
}
```